# Django - Order by custom function

Tags: django

I have multiple `projects` in my `subprogram`, each with a different cost which I'm calculating in a custom function in my `project` model. How can I create a subprogram function that returns a list of `projects` ordered by the `costs` function in the projects model? Is this possible todo?

**Subprogram model:**

```py
class Subprogram(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def projects_sorted(self):
        return self.project_set.all().order_by('costs')
```

**Project Model:**

```py
class Project(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=100)
    subprogram = models.ForeignKey(Subprogram, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def costs(self):
        costTotals = 0
        costs = self.costs_set.all()
        for bcost in costs:
            costTotals += bcost.cost
        return costTotals
```

Comment: `costs_set` implies you also have another model please show that too in your question. Also show the declaration of your Project model properly (example `class Project(models.Model)` and fix the indentation of your methods.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work (untested):

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

class Subprogram(...):

    ...

    def projects_sorted(self):
        return self.project_set.annotate(
            total_cost = Sum('cost_set__cost')
        ).order_by('total_cost')
```